# Mongoose Summing Up subdocument array elements having same alias

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, q

I have a document like this:

```
  _id:'someId',
  sales: 
     [
      {
       _id:'111',
       alias:'xxx',
       amount:500,
       name: Apple, //items with same alias always have same name and quantity
       quantity:2

     },
     {
       _id:'222',
       alias:'abc',
       amount:100,
       name: Orange,
       quantity:14
     },
     {
      _id:'333',
      alias:'xxx',
      amount:300,
      name: Apple, //items with same alias always have same name and quantity
      quantity:2
     }
    ]
```

The **alias** field is here to 'group' items/documents whenever they appear to have same alias i.e to be 'embeded' as one with the amount summed up.

I need to display some sort of a report in such a way that those elements which have same alias they should be displayed as *ONE* and the others which doesn't share same alias to remain as they are.

Example, For the sample document above, I need an output like this

```
[
 {
   alias:'xxx',
   amount:800
 },
 {
   alias:'abc',
   amount:100
 }
]
```

WHAT I HAVE TRIED

```
MyShop.aggregate([

{$group:{

 _id: "$_id",
 sales:{$last :"$sales"}
},

{$project:{
  "sales.amount":1
}}

}

])
```

This just displays as a 'list' regardless of the alias. How do I achieve summing up amount based on the alias?

Comment: Do you wan the sum for each document or calculated across all documents?

Comment: @thammada I want the sum for all subdocuments HAVING THE SAME ALIAS

Comment: Yes, but in your example you did not include the original document, so It's possible you want this as the result of your query, not just part of a document. But I saw your comment on the first answer, I assume it's the same structure as the answer that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using `$group`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$sales"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        alias: "$sales.alias"
      },
      sales: {
        $first: "$sales"
      },
      _idsInvolved: {
        $push: "$sales._id"
      },
      amount: {
        $sum: "$sales.amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      sales: {
        $push: {
          $mergeObjects: [
            "$sales",
            {
              alias: "$_id.alias",
              amount: "$amount",
              _idsInvolved: "$_idsInvolved"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KUFvYQx04l8)

Comment: What if I need to return `name` and `quantity` fields too? They are static/common to each row/document returned. Can you show how to return them?

Comment: do you want only name and quantity specifically or actually the rest of the fields if there are more fields in the future?

Comment: I want the rest of the fields, all of them

Comment: Please see that other question, i have an issue there

Comment: @Amani I already updated the answer on your other question

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "sales": {
        "$map": {
          "input": {
            "$setUnion": [
              "$sales.alias"
            ]
          },
          "as": "m",
          "in": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                "a": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$sales",
                    "as": "d",
                    "cond": {
                      "$eq": [
                        "$$d.alias",
                        "$$m"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "in": {
                "amount": {
                  "$sum": "$$a.amount"
                },
                "alias": "$$m",
                "_idsInvolved": "$$a._id"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XYCwbk4B4IZ)

Comment: One more thing please I forgot to add in the original question. I need the id's involved in the summing up to also be included in the array.. in the example above it should be like


    `"sales": [
      {
        "alias": "abc",
        "amount": 100,
        "_idsInvolved": ['111','333']

      },
      {
        "alias": "xxx",
        "amount": 800,
        "_idsInvolved": ['222']
      }
    ]`

Comment: I tried the updated answer on mongoPlayground  and it doesn't give those id's in array as specified in my comment..It doesn't work

Comment: Now have a look

Comment: I've upvoted your answer..it really solves the problem, except that when I try to return data which are common/static to both items with same alias it doesn't give them.
This is to say that, all items which have same alias have some data in common(in my example in question it is `name` and `quantity` fields... Can you just show how to return them too?

Comment: Check the `"_idsInvolved"` ... Here you can add more key underneath

Comment: I tried the `_idsInvolved` way, but it returns them inside an array. I just want them to be returned normally (not in array) just as 


`{
"_idsInvolved": [ '222'],"
"alias": "abc",
"amount":100,
"name": "Apple"
}`